# File smime.p7s- extract hash code

Tags: javascript, python, html, ios

Good morning I am a newcomer to programming; I wanted to ask you:

1) Is the P7s file a certificate signing the hash code of the email?

2) Is there a program for extracting the hash code of the email from the P7s file?

3) if I change some email data (for example the date) the hash code changes; I wonder What are the consequences on the P7s

Thanks to those who will answer me

Comment: How are the tags related to the question? This seems to be more suited for [IT Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) though I would suggest reading their [how to ask](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/asking) pages first.

Comment: With that tags i have read many answers but nobody explain my question.....

Comment: Well, first of all, that's not how [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) works here. You should tag the post _appropriately_ based on the question. Tagging it with javascript, python, etc. tells people that it's about code that uses those languages (which this post isn't). If this _is_ about code you've written, then you should [include the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the post. It's also maybe because you're asking multiple questions on 1 post, with Q#2 seeming a bit [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try to improve your question. Good luck.